# Retreiving a list of records from web forms

Tags: asp.net, ado

I've got this issue.
I have a web form where users insert their data (name, surname, date of birth...) and 2 types of address. The problem comes (obviously) when I have to retrieve the entire list of address (I always get the first record of the database two times).

This is the code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Address where idUsers = @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
rdr = (cmd.ExecuteReader());
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
  rdr.Read();

  AddressType.Items[AddressType.SelectedIndex].Selected = false;
  AddressType.Items.FindByValue(rdr["idAddressType"].ToString()).Selected = true;
  txtStreet.Text = rdr["streetAddress"].ToString();
  txtCity.Text = rdr["cityAddress"].ToString();
  Nation.Items[Nation.SelectedIndex].Selected = false;
  Nation.Items.FindByValue(rdr["idNations"].ToString()).Selected = true;

  tblAddress2.Visible = true;
  AddressType2.Items[AddressType2.SelectedIndex].Selected = false;
  AddressType2.Items.FindByValue(rdr["idAddressType"].ToString()).Selected = true;
  txtStreet2.Text = rdr["streetAddress"].ToString();
  txtCity2.Text = rdr["cityAddress"].ToString();
  Nation2.Items[Nation2.SelectedIndex].Selected = false;
  Nation2.Items.FindByValue(rdr["idNations"].ToString()).Selected = true;
}
rdr.Close();
```

What can I do? Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `rdr.Read();` before `tblAddress2.Visible = true;`

Otherwise you're just reading the same row again. It won't know to move to the next row unless you tell it to.

Comment: Thanks ADyson! But it only works on text boxes and NOT with DROPDOWNLISTS! Can you help me in this case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not really, because I've no idea what code you've tried in relation to drop-down lists or what specific issue you're having. I'd guess you probably need to use a loop to get all the results instead of just a fixed number, but that's purely a guess. If you can't figure it out then I suggest you ask new question with the relevant code in it

Comment: I can have a max of 2 address (1 is required, the second is an optional). I don't think I need to iterate with a for loop!

Comment: I see. So what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: The problem is the following: when I retrieve the addresses in my web form by clicking the button EDIT, the values in the DROPDOWN LISTS of the first address are wrong (I can retrieve all the data in the second address but for the first address the VALUES in the DROPDOWN LISTS are wrong!!). This problem occurs only in the DROPDOW LIST of the first address!!

Comment: The first address iherits automatically the VALUES of the DROPDOWN LISTS of the second address

Comment: you really need to ask a new question with the code for it. It's hard to tell what's really going on just from a description. If you put the link to it here, I can take a look